# Laravel 5.1 I cant update model $user

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have this function where I want to update user background image so I write:

```
public function updateBg(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $this->validate($request, [
            'background' => 'image|max:10000',
            // validate also other fields here
        ]);
        // checking file is valid.
        if (!$request->file('background')->isValid()) return redirect()->back()->withErrors(["background" => "File is corrupt"]);

        // file is valid
        $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/Custaccounts/'.$user->id; // upload path
        $extension = $request->file('background')->getClientOriginalExtension(); // getting image extension
        $ran = str_random(5);
        $photo  = $ran.'.'.$extension;

        $request->file('background')->move($destinationPath, $photo); // uploading file to given path

        $bg = $user->id.'/'.$photo;
dd($bg);
        $user->update(['background' => $bg]);

        return Redirect::back();

            }
```

this line wont work:             `$user->update(['background' => $bg]);` dd($bg) give me right string and image is uploaded just I cant update my 'background; field ...

also when I write:

```
    $user->update(['background' => $bg, 'name'=>'John']);
```

name is updated but background not... at user model background field is fillable of cource

Comment: Is it `fillable` or `guarded` on your model?

Comment: its fillable...

Comment: protected $fillable = ['name', 'photo','color', 'email', 'password','admin','jobtitle','phone','mobile','restaurant','address','address2','city','state','zip','country','url','twitter','facebook','capacity','email_for_invoices','vat','type','tos','vatrate','lat','lng','booking','validity','viaurl','background'];

Comment: So do you get an error in your `laravel.log`? When you say it won't work, what happens?

Comment: no, there is no erro at laravel log

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. And if the field exists in the database (with the correct datatype), and is fillable on your model, I can't think of anything more to suggest other than following the path through the Laravel source code and seeing where it fails.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160974/discussion-between-aleks-per-and-fubar).

Comment: VERY STRANGE becouse I try now and I write         $user->update(['address2' => $bg]);
 and everything is OK... but when I rename that field into bg_img or similar and try aain, wont work... also all fields is fillable in User model!

Comment: What do your migrations for the user table look like?

Comment: When you renamed to bg_img, did you remember to update your fillable array?

Comment: yes, sure ... but dont work... I put address2 as field I dont use so I use it for bg image ...

Comment: @AleksPer see my answer hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem you are trying to update the bg field form User table.. Your code must work. If not working Try this:-

```
Remove this :- $user->update(['background' => $bg]);
Update this :- User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->update(['background' => $bg]);
```

Hope it helps!